# mstmp, Google Apps

Tags: email, smtp, g-suite

I'm using Google Apps for my domains email, but should I use mstmp and hook it into sending via Google Apps? The reason I ask this is if I have to send high volumes of email, for example people signing up to my site in quick succession and receiving emails, or batch sending of emails, will Google support/allow this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps only supports sending a maximum of 2,000 e-mails per day, per account.

Pasted from their FAQ:

> Q: I have to send out a lot of emails
>   on a daily basis. Does Google Apps
>   have a sending limit?
>
> A: Each account can currently send
>   email to 2,000 external recipients per
>   day to prevent abuse of our system and
>   to help fight spam. If one of your
>   mail accounts reaches the limit, the
>   account will be temporarily unable to
>   send mail.

Source: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/faq.html